# Reset the identity of a column in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have created an application and I have used this piece of code (which I have found on the Internet) to clear all the data and reset the Identity of the Identity columns of the tables.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?' 
GO 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''?'', RESEED, 0)'
GO

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO
```

But I have two tables which do not have `Identity` columns and that gives me a problem saying:

> Msg 7997, Level 16, State 1, Line 616
>   'SupplierBalance' does not contain an identity column.
>
> Msg 7997, Level 16, State 1, Line 616
>   'CustomerBalance' does not contain an identity column.

I want to know if there is a way to reset the identity of the columns of the tables, which only have identity columns without getting an error.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe using `TRUNCATE` will reseed your `IDENTITY` column so you dont have to issue a `RESEED` command.

Comment: Afaik @felix is correct. Truncate table will not only reseed your identity colums, it's also the fastest way to delete all table's content, as it's not registered in the sql log.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, contrary to popular belief. `TRUNCATE` is *minimally* logged. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/delete-vs-truncate/30347#30347

Comment: @felix thanks for the great link!

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE ?' does not work in my code. Whenever I use it, it says there is still a foreign key constrain left in a table

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `DELETE` and issuing a `RESEED` command, you may want to use `TRUNCATE` instead.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?' 
GO 

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL' 
GO
```

Using `TRUNCATE` is also more efficient than using `DELETE`. According to Paul White in his answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30325/delete-vs-truncate/30347#30347):

> Yes.  `TRUNCATE TABLE` is more efficient for a number of reasons:
>
> 1. Fewer locks may be needed. Truncation typically requires only a single schema modification lock at the table level (and exclusive
>    locks on each extent deallocated). Deletion might acquire locks at a
>    lower (row or page) granularity as well as exclusive locks on any
>    pages deallocated.
> 2. Only truncation guarantees that all pages are deallocated from a heap table. Deletion may leave empty pages in a heap even if an
>    exclusive table lock hint is specified (for example if a
>    row-versioning isolation level is enabled for the database).
> 3. Truncation is always minimally logged (regardless of the recovery model in use). Only page deallocation operations are recorded in the
>    transaction log.
> 4. Truncation can use deferred drop if the object is 128 extents or larger in size. Deferred drop means the actual deallocation work is
>    performed asynchronously by a background server thread.

Additionally, I beleve `sp_MSforEachTable` is undocumented. You can find an alternative method [**here.**](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm)

---

Since some of your tables have FK reference, you cannot use `TRUNCATE` without dropping the constraints. But still you can use `DELETE`. The problem now is with `RESEED`, that it produces an error on tables without `IDENTITY` column. To solve that, here is a dynamic SQL you can execute. It'll only `RESEED` when the table has an `IDENTITY` column:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SET NOCOUNT ON;';

WITH Cte(tableName, hasIdentity) AS(
    SELECT t.name, CAST(ISNULL(ic.object_id, 0) AS BIT)
    FROM sys.tables t
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic
        ON t.object_id = ic.object_id
    WHERE t.type = 'U'
)
SELECT @sql = @sql + CHAR(10) + 
    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(tableName) + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;' + CHAR(10) +
    N'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(tableName) + ';' + CHAR(10) + 
    CASE
        WHEN hasIdentity = 1 THEN 
            N'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''' + QUOTENAME(tableName) + ''', RESEED, 0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS;' + CHAR(10)
        ELSE ''
    END +
    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(tableName) + ' WITH CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;'
FROM Cte

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: 'TRUNCATE TABLE ?' does not work in my code. Whenever I use it, it says there is still a foreign key constrain left in a table.

Comment: You can't use `TRUNCATE` when there's an `FK` reference.

Comment: Perform delete and then fire reseed is better solution, truncate is not working even though the tables have no data but having reference column somewhere in other table.

Answer (score 0):

1) 1st Argument Table Name

2) 2nd Keyword ('RESEED') for Reset Identity

3) 3rd Next Identity value

```
  DBCC CHECKIDENT ('ResetIDClmn', RESEED, 5)
```

Example

```
if OBJECT_ID('ResetIDClmn') is not null
Begin
Drop table ResetIDClmn
 End
        Create table ResetIDClmn (P_Id int identity,abc varchar(10),PRIMARY KEY (P_Id))
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')

        Select * from ResetIDClmn

        --truncate table ResetIDClmn 

        delete ResetIDClmn where P_Id>5

        DBCC CHECKIDENT ('ResetIDClmn', RESEED, 5)
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Insert Into ResetIDClmn (abc) values ('sdfsfd')
        Select * from ResetIDClmn
```

Comment: running DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[JBPM_TOKENVARIABLEMAP]', RESEED, 5) on my table resulted in Msg 7997, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'JBPM_TOKENVARIABLEMAP' does not contain an identity column.